# Can we have a search filter to exclude questions closed as duplicates?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Back before the procedure for closing duplicates was changed, the text "Possible duplicate:" was inserted into question bodies.

And that made it relatively easy to search for questions that were candidates for re-opening or deletion, by searching for:

> closed:1 migrated:0 -"possible duplicate:"

But that's not useful any more, now that the "possible duplicate:" text is not inserted into questions closed as duplicates, nor is the "This question already has an answer here:" text.

So, can we have something that we **can** search on, to exclude duplicates? Either by putting "[Duplicate]" in the title, or adding search term "duplicate:[0|1]", or something?

Comment: I laughed because this is a duplicate.